# An elegant way to write shell commands for both windows and linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, shell

I am trying to create a python script which would run some shell commands on both linux and windows platforms. But since powershell and shell are different, each platform needs its own commands

Solution that I've found so far is to convert commands written for Linux to Windows with str.replace().

```
def linux2windowsConvert(cmd):
    if 'win32' == sys.platform:
        cmd = cmd.replace('/', '//').replace('\\', '//').replace(';', '&')
        cmd = cmd.replace('cat', 'type')
        return cmd
```

I couldn't find more elegant and stable solution so I just wonder is there any other way to write cross-platform shell code?

Comment: Can you use the same shell on both OSes?

Comment: long story short  - no :) script should work with both powershell and shell
And I don't mind converting commands through my function. I'm just wondering if there are  any beautiful solutions for such cases.

Comment: There is no easy way apart from what has already been suggested: Install PoSh on linux or [enable linux subsystem](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/install-and-start-bash-in-windows-10-anniversary-update/) on windows.

Comment: Or commit to supporting both powershell and sh in the python code.

Comment: What happens when you want to invoke something like ```truncate.exe``` and it tries to run ```truntypee.exe``` on Windows instead?

Comment: oh, that's a bug you're totally right. that's why I was looking for another way to do it. I guess I should try to use same shell on every os

Comment: You don't need to convert `/` to `\` if using PowerShell. It will accept both ways. The difference is in accessing the root folder.